# For loop variable, confused about single and double quotes

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I'd like to make the following code a for loop to make everything read better, but I can't seem to get the quotes right and end up with a blank page

```
if ($_POST['week'])
{
  $week = $_POST['week'];
}
//or check for a value submitted by the week menu
elseif ($_POST["user_week1"] == "week1") {
  $week = "1";
}
elseif ($_POST["user_week2"] == "week2") {
  $week = "2";
}
else if ($_POST["user_week3"] == "week3") {
  $week = "3";
}
else if ($_POST["user_week4"] == "week4") {
  $week = "4";
}
else if ($_POST["user_week5"] == "week5") {
  $week = "5";
}
else if ($_POST["user_week6"] == "week6") {
  $week = "6";
}
else {
  $week = "1";
}
```

I tried to do:

```
if ($_POST['week'])
{
  $week = $_POST['week'];
}
for ($i = 1; $i<7; $i++)
{
  else if ($_POST["user_week'.$i.'"] == "week'.$i.'") {
    $week = $i;
}
}
else {
  $week = "1";
}
```

But that didn't work out too well, I tried using double quotes instead of single around the variables, plus '" and "' to no avail.

Can anyone help with this, or point me towards a good resource on single and double quotes for variables?

Comment: `$_POST["user_week".$i] == "week".$i`

Comment: "a good resource" ---http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: As you mentioned you want to make change to read it better. From readability perspective I would use switch instead of loops or else if..

Comment: Have you considered using arrays yet? `$_POST["user_week"]` can become one using `<input name="user_week[2]">`.

Comment: Can you gentlemen give examples of those methods?

Comment: Example of switch case??? check out http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you all igrnoring the fact that the `else if` mustn`t be there!?

What you should do is the following

```
$week = "1";
if ($_POST['week']) {
  $week = $_POST['week'];
} else {
  for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
    if ($_POST["user_week" . $i] == "week" . $i) {
      $week = $i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't ignoring it, I was just too blind to see it ;) This worked, but you need another } at the end to close the else, which I got wrong in my original code.

Answer (score -1):

```
  elseif ($_POST['user_week' . $i] == 'week' . $i)
```

above correction should work

Comment: "correction should work" --- not actually. He has an `elseif` not paired to any `if`. And another `else` is tied with `for` o_O

Comment: Well he is confused about the single and double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I didn't copy the entire code, all good now! Thanks for all the help folks!